# Работа с таблицей Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку (ошибки)! Дана задача со следующим условием:

"В исходной таблице два столбца с названиями name и score.
Напишите программный код, который преобразует исходную таблицу следующим образом:
Необходимо удалить те строки, у которых отсутствуют данные в первом столбце (name).
Отсутствующие значения во втором столбце (score) необходимо заменить средним по данному столбцу.
Результат необходимо сохранить в файл output.csv . Используйте методы read_csv(), dropna(), fillna(), to_csv()."

Моё решение:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df = df.dropna(subset=['name'])
mean_score = df['score'].mean()
df['score'] = df['score'].fillna(mean_score)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: вы код запускали? какие ошибки получаете?

Comment: Гипотеза. Может быть, среднее по `score` нужно считать **до** удаления строк с NaN в `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял случайные данные

```
edgomessilva    345
oyejhon     654
esales  456
emily   456
floid   345
Donyendro   654
Super
Puper
    123
    345
    456
```

Добавил разделитель и заголовки

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',delimiter='\t', names=['name','score'])
```

ваш код работает

```
            name  score
0  edgomessilva    345.0
1        oyejhon   654.0
2         esales   456.0
3          emily   456.0
4          floid   345.0
5      Donyendro   654.0
6           Super  485.0
7           Puper  485.0
```

Может у вас данные не корректные.
Покажите исходные данные в текстовом виде.

Comment: Работаю в Яндекс.Контест, почему-то при каждой отправке выдаёт WA (неправильный ответ). Данные для ввода: name,score
name1,87
name2,100
name3,98
name4,
,
,78
name5,67

Comment: в эти данные добавил переносы строки, тоже все работает, даже не требуется указывать имена столбцов и разделитель.