# Работа с таблицей в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть вот такая задача:

В исходной таблице два столбца с названиями **name** и **score**.
Напишите программный код, который в исходной таблице удалит те строки, у которых отсутствуют данные в первом столбце (**name**). Отсутствующие значения во втором столбце (**score**) необходимо заменить средним по данному столбцу.
Результат необходимо сохранить в файл *output.csv*.
Используйте методы `read_csv()`, `dropna()`, `fillna()`, `to_csv()`.

Мое решение:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delimiter=',', names=['name','score'])

df = df.dropna(subset=['name'])

df['score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['score'], errors='coerce')

mean_score = df['score'].mean()

df['score'] = df['score'].fillna(mean_score)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

При выводе получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо убрать первую строчку 0,name,88.0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555468/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с таблицей Python Pandas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555468/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-python-pandas)

Comment: не дубликат, у меня проблема другая - надо убрать строчку под индексом 0, чтобы к ней среднее не присваивалось, но задача та же

Comment: @Лина Ковалева  какое условие для удаления  строчки под индексом 0, там не отсутствуют данные( в первом столбце (name)), среднее подставляется, в чем проблема?